# Get Record based on table result with Three Tables

Tags: mysql

I have four tables, where the data should be checked for 1st table, if doesn't exist, then should check for 2nd table and goes on...

Currently following approach can be followed

```
1. Have union all on the tables and find out the above based on priority (Or)
2. Run each query from the application and verify and goes one by one (Or)
3. Using CASE and NOT_EXIST option to find out the rows accordingly
```

Problems:

```
1. Problem with JPA if all columns are extracted with asterisk (*) since count(c.*)
   is not supported in SQL
2. Performance and unnecessary multiple query from application which needs to be
   avoided in second approach
3. Makes the query has very complex and not interested to proceed
```

What would be the best practice to be followed on this use case?

Thanks

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE, including indices and FKs (for one table if the structures are completely equal, for all tables if not).

Comment: @Akina just take a simple example, if company has the employee record, then goes into employee table,  if employee table has record, go into employee details. if the company doesn't have emp record -> return company. if company has employee record, check employee detail available. if not, return employee record..similarly it goes to the last level.

Comment: What you are writing is not like CREATE TABLE scripts.